# Breake mail text into two row

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to breake text from mail into two row. 
This is how it's look right now

```
Ukupno novih korisnika: 28 Ukupno izmjenjenih korisnika:47
```

But I want something like this

```
Ukupno novih korisnika: 28
Ukupno izmjenjenih korisnika:47
```

SO far I try

```
 myMail.Body = @"Ukupno novih korisnika: " + noviKorisnika + "\n" + "\r\n" + "\t" +
                          @"Ukupno izmjenjenih korisnika: " + izmjenjenihKorisnika;
```

Comment: Is it a HTML email? If so, you'll need to use a `<br>` tag for a hard line break.

Comment: Yes, it's HTML email

Comment: Glad I could help. I added this as an answer you can accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML emails, you'll need to use a `<br>` tag for a hard line break.

```
myMail.Body = (
  "Ukupno novih korisnika: " + noviKorisnika + "<br>\n" + 
  "Ukupno izmjenjenih korisnika: " + izmjenjenihKorisnika
);
```

Comment: Without \n, only "<br />"

Comment: It's clearer to use both, in case some poor soul has to read the HTML mail in plain text mode.